# Python 3.7 pytest coverage marks 'if' blocks without 'else' statements as uncovered

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.7, coverage.py, pytest-cov

When I run test, code in the "if" block is called and executed. However pytest-coverage marks it as missing(coverage decreases).

It's uncovered if I write like this

```
if some_working_condition:
    do_smth()
```

But If I add an "else" statement it marks if block as covered

```
if some_working_condition:
    do_smth()
else:
    print("failed")
```

I use python==3.7.12 pytest==6.2.5 pytest-cov==3.0.0 coverage==6.2

Why it works like that and how I can resolve it? I can not add else statement, because action in "if" must be executed in certain condition without an action for "else"

Comment: The if-statement shouldn't be marked as uncovered.  Can you show exactly what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that's the case, but in case the code inside the `if` is being covered but the `if` line itself isn't, it means the `if True` case is being tested, but the `if False` case is not. Be sure to test both branches.